# Radiation from an accelerated charge

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, acceleration

Today, I was given a brief introduction about electromagnetism in my school. My teacher told me that Maxwell proposed that *if a charge performs an accelerated motion, then it consistently radiates energy and thus it's energy shall be lowered* as time passes . But, I couldn't understand that how it is meaningful if we define acceleration as a relative property.

For example, consider a charge *Q* moving with an acceleration of *'a'* with respect to say a frame *S* . Suppose two observers **A** and **B** .
**A** being accelerated with respect to *S* with same acceleration as that of the charge i.e. *a* and **B** being un-accelerated with respect to *S* .

According to **A** , charge *Q* does not accelerate and hence it shall not radiate any energy.While, according to **B** , charge *Q* shall lose and radiate some energy as time passes.

Does that mean charge *Q* **radiate** and **not radiate** energy at the same time ? What am I missing here ?

Comment: Thank you for the link but I saw the question which is very same as mine. However the answer given do not answer my question. The discussion on that question further led to discussion on topics which wasn't related to my question . I expect that a more-to-the-point answer would be given.

Comment: Please point out if the discussion didn't divert away and I do not understand them, because I am new to physics and physics SE.